# JS Regex: Double slash splitting along with other characters

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a split statement in my JavaScript that will split spaces and semicolons, but I want to split double slashes as well. I cannot figure out how to include a double slash along with the space and semicolon.

```
line = lines[i].split(/[\s;]+/);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The alternation, or pipe (`|`) operator is fundamental to regexp. It means to match either this **or** that. You want to match either the space/semi-colon **or** a double slash. It's quite a quick jump from there to using the pipe.

Comment: How do you want to split something like `"foo//;bar"`?

Answer (score 0):

so assuming that by "double slashes" you mean a double forward slash ( "//" ) you are going to want to do something like the following:

```
line = lines[i].split(/[\s;]+|\/{2}/);
```

Note that the matching options are being moved from between brackets, because when placed within the brackets, "{", "2", and "}" would be interpreted literally, rather than as a pattern

Comment: The parens are going to cause the splitting sequences to be included in the output, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will not behave properly in the presence of a double slash or semi-colon surrounded by spaces. It will generate empty strings in the output. This regexp handles that case:

```
/(?:\s|;|\/\/)+/
```

In other words, split on any sequence composed of spaces, semi-colons, or double slashes.

```js
var re = /(?:\s|;|\/\/)+/;

var input = "Some stuff; more stuff // last stuff";

console.log(input.split(re));
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me either. It didn't detect my double slash, and it stopped detecting my spaces and semicolons.

Comment: @C.Shoe Try running the snippet.